# Unable to Authenticate using Kerberos in Windows for ActiveDirectoryIntegrated

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, kerberos

I am not much knowing about Kerberos Authentication, when i tried, unable to Authenticate using Kerberos in Windows for ActiveDirectoryIntegrated

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.ini");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;database=testExistingDB"
                + ";authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos";
        Connection con = driver.connect(connectionUrl, null);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println(con.getMetaData().getDriverName());
```

Getting below error with exception details,

> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: Password is required for managed user
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerADAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthTokenIntegrated(SQLServerADAL4JUtils.java:113)
> ... 17 more

Can some one please let me know where is actually issue available.?

i did follow this documention for krb5.ini to generate
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Please be informed that, i am able to do DLL based AD Integrated authentication, issue only with Kerberos based AD integrated authentication.
Please let me know in case of any procedure is not followed.

Comment: Have you join your machine in Azure AD?

Comment: of course, it is.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided service_principal and keytab file for authentication purpose.